# Animate div when the scrollbar reaches certain position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

My website at the moment has three sections in a single scroll layout. With a Heading for two sections: About & Contact (these are div boxes) that animate when you scroll to the bottom of the page. What I'm trying to achieve is having the animation take place when the user scrolls down and hits the bottom of each (div box) section as opposed to the bottom of the website.

I believe I need to implement the .offset() function but unsure if that is correct?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CSS

```
.header {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 500px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background:red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS

```
var header = $('.header'),
extra = 10; // In case you want to trigger it a bit sooner than exactly at the bottom.

header.css({ opacity: '0', display: 'block' });

$(window).scroll(function() {

var scrolledLength = ( $(window).height() +extra) + $(window).scrollTop(),
   documentHeight =  $(document).height();

console.log( 'Scroll length: ' + scrolledLength + ' Document height: ' + documentHeight )

if( scrolledLength >= documentHeight ) {

   header
      .addClass('top')
      .stop().animate({ top: '20', opacity: '1' }, 800);
}
else if ( scrolledLength <= documentHeight && header.hasClass('top') ) {           
    header
       .removeClass('top')
       .stop().animate({ top: '500', opacity: '0' }, 800);
  } 
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SFPpf/480/

Comment: Since the stackoverflow community says that asking if a link to a github repo doesn't work, I'm going to post the link here.  Does this work: https://github.com/FREE-FROM-CMS/load_more  one of the vars in the top of engine.js is probably what you need to use, but if not you can do an on mouseover targeting the content divs.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I follow.. forgive me as I am only new and still learning (slowly ha) @php_purest

Comment: What type of animation are you doing?

Comment: Did it do what you wanted it to?

Comment: You'll see the animation I am trying to achieve in the JS Fiddle I have created. You'll notice that it begins once the user has scrolled to the bottom of the document.

- I am trying to get the animation to begin once the user has scrolled to the bottom of the div box called 'fillWindow" instead of the whole document.

-As for the animation, the div box called 'header' animates upwards along the y-axis and fades in from 0 to 100% too. then reverse once the user has left the point in the page. @php_purest

Comment: Since you say load more of the document take a look at: https://github.com/FREE-FROM-CMS/load_more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like position() would be better in this case. The position method is relative to the document whereas offset is relative to the parent element. It returns an object with the properties "top" and "left". It can only return the position of one element at a time, so for the first div, you would need to use first() and eq() to get a specific one.

The bottom of a .fillWindow will be its vertical position + its height.

```
var $fillWindow = $(".fillWindow").first(), // or eq() for others
    position = $fillWindow.position(),
    height = $fillWindow.height();
    //bottom = position.top + height;
```

scrollTop() can now be used to check when the user scrolls past the .fillWindow.

```
if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= position.top ) {
    // do the animation here
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Edit: I just caught my mistake. It should be $(window).scrollTop(). You should also just test for scrollTop being at the top of the .fillWindow.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your input.. I have inserted the suggested code into the JS Fiddle and unfortunately I'm unable to get it to work? - here is the updated JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SFPpf/481/